# Are software-specific questions okay?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, asking-questions

I checked out the FAQ and searched Meta. Couldn't figure it out.

I'm wondering how to change the default save format in Notepad++.  It's not in the docs.  What I typically get when I ask Q&A communities about something software-specific is: "Why don't you just e-mail the distributor?"

I know a common response from Open-Source software developers is, "We're giving out something for free.  Why should you feel it's okay to demand more?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are already 242 [notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) questions, so yes asking a software-specific question, even about Notepad++ is perfectly on-topic

Answer (score 8):

Let  me quote the FAQ real quick:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - ***computer software***

(emphasis mine)

… so, yes, your question is on-topic :)

And please, don't refrain from asking questions just because they are specific. Just make them good questions that can be useful for others. Then you're good to go.